# MQTT Mosquitto Broker does not sent all retained messages

Tags: c#, wpf, mqtt, mosquitto

I am having problems with receiving all retained messages from Mosquitto broker.
The broker is started, I have a separate program which populates the broker with 3000 messages with retain set to true.
When I connect using my client I only get 1020 messages.
What did I miss and how to get all retained messages.

I am using a WPF app (Net Framework 4.6.2) and a python script. The result is the same with both.
Also, I am using a wildcard to subscribe.

Mosquitto ver 2.0.10
Config file as follows:

```
acl_file ./configs/acl.acl
password_file ./configs/pwfile
allow_anonymous false
listener 8883
cafile ./certs/ca.crt
certfile ./certs/root.crt
keyfile ./certs/root.key
tls_version tlsv1.2
```

ACL File:

```
user TestUser
topic read public/read/alarm/#
topic write public/write/alarm/#
```

Comment: Just to be clear, there are 3000 distinct topics with retained messages and your client has subscribed to all of them (or a wildcard that would include them all)?

Comment: Yes, the topics are organized like this public/DeviceSegment/DeviceId/[attribute]. There are 6 attributes available. Every message informs about the state of a given attribute. When I populate the broker i Send 3000 messages (3000 distinct topics) which adds up to 500 devices.

I always get 1020 retained messages, regardless if I subscribe like so 'public/#' or like so 'public/+/+/description' (description is one of the attributes.

Comment: What QOS are you publishing and subscribing at

Comment: I Tried QOS 0, 1 and two. Same with publishing.

The thing that is most puzzling to me is why am I getting a limited number of messages regardless of the wildcard. It is as if the client isn't notifying the broker and therefore it does not transmit more messages. I did one more test using mosquito_sub.exe and I have the same result.

Comment: Also, If I start the broker, than the client and only than I start the simulator and populate the broker than I receive all messages. The problem starts only when I start the broker than populate it using the simulator and than start the client and subscribe.

Comment: Edit the question to include your mosquitto.conf file and the version information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [mosquitto man page](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-conf-5.html):

> `max_inflight_messages count`
>
> The maximum number of outgoing QoS 1 or 2 messages that can be in the process of being transmitted simultaneously. This includes messages currently going through handshakes and messages that are being retried. Defaults to 20. Set to 0 for no maximum. If set to 1, this will guarantee in-order delivery of messages.

> `max_queued_messages count`
>
> The maximum number of QoS 1 or 2 messages to hold in the queue (per client) above those messages that are currently in flight. Defaults to 1000. Set to 0 for no maximum (not recommended). See also the queue_qos0_messages and max_queued_bytes options.

As your configuration does not contain either of these options the defaults of 20 (max inflight) and 1000 (max queued) kick in, so receiving a maximum of 1020 messages when you connect is the expected result. If you wish Mosquitto to store more messages then add `max_queued_messages x` to your `mosquitto.conf` (where x is the max number of messages or 0 for unlimited).

Comment: And just like that you saved my day. Thank you, much appreciated.

Comment: Hi, take a look at [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77300791/c-sharp-mqttnet-library-not-all-retained-message-are-received), I experienced a different woking case with different clients.