# C# MqttNet library: not all retained message are received

Tags: c#, mqtt, mosquitto, mqttnet

I'm having a problem using MQTTnet library with retained message.
I use V5 protocol, `qos=2` and `WithCleanStart(false).WithSessionExpiryInterval(3600)`.

On the server (mosquitto) max_queued_messages = 1000 (default).

Expected and tested function (**no retained** message, it works as I expected):

1. Subrcriber dies
2. Publisher sends 2000 messages
3. Subscriber up again and receive 1000 message
   **Perfect**.

With **retained** message on 2000 different topic (1 message per topic) This is what I have on a third-party software (mqtt explorer):

1. Subrcriber dies
2. Publisher sends 2000 messages on 2000 different topic (1 message per topic)
3. Subscriber up again and receive 2000 message
   **Perfect**.

But with MQTTnet library on my c# program I have:

1. Subrcriber dies
2. Publisher sends 2000 messages on 2000 different topic (1 message per topic)
3. Subscriber up again and receive **1000**-**1040** message
   **Why?** It seams that it's not interest if messages are retained or not..

I suppose that there is a parameters on the MQTTnet library, I checked but I'm not able to find it.
Do you have any ideas?

P.S.
On not dying subsriber everithing is correct:

1. Publisher sends 2000 messages on 2000 different topic (1 message per topic)
2. Subscriber receive 2000 message.
   **Perfect**

in [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67344858/mqtt-mosquitto-broker-does-not-sent-all-retained-messages) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71629368/mqttnet-mqtt-client-cannot-receive-all-the-messages-that-were-published-by-mqt) is suggested a server configuration, **but with a different client (mqtt explorer) everithing works correctly.** So I don't think is possible a server configuration. That's why a suppose a library configuration (so.. no duplicated thread).

Mqttserver Mosquitto configuration all as defaults.

Comment: In the case of max_queued_messages is "shared" between retained and not retained message, if I publish 1000 retained and next 1000 not retained,  the sessioned-subscriber which message will receive? Where i can find some detailed documentation abouth this?

Comment: `max_queued_messages` should not impact retained messages iirc. The only documentation will be the mosquitto man page and the source code.

Comment: @hardillb I agree with you.. ok.. may the source be with us.. I'll report back what I discover

Comment: "1000 retained and next 1000 not retained" - the order is important here; a retained message is still delivered; subscribed clients receive it immediately and its queued for offline clients (so you may receive two copies when you reconnect; the message as sent and the retained copy). This will have an impact on when you hit the `max_queued_messages` limit. There are also other factors (V5 has a lot more options than v3) so showing us a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.